# Passive switch that detects when a door is opened

Tags: passive-components

*Background* In my school, we are assigned lockers and I am trying my best to make mine as impressive as possible, at this point I've build a custom shelf for it and put up some LEDs. The problem is that I manually have to reach for the on/off-switch for the lights, and let us be honest, that is not really something you should have to do in 2019. Hence, I'm trying to figure out how to make the lights go on when I open the locker.

*Current progress* Firstly I though about automating the process using an Arduino and motion sensor/distance sensor to see whether the door was open, but since the whole apparatus would have to be turned on 24/7, even the 50mW that I calculated that it would require was to much for two AA batteries in series. Then a friend suggested that I put in a button that would be pressed when the door was closed, opening the circuit with the LEDs, and closing the circuit when the door was opened. This would be very battery effective, but it is hard to place a button correctly, and it would propably come off if I accidentally closed the door with to much force. Today, I thought about using a LED as a "solarpanel", detecting that it was dark when the door was shut, and detecting increased luminosity when the door was opened, activating a transistor and closing the circuit. Problem is that a) I tried to build a prototype, but I didn't succed in powering the transistor using two different power sources, and b) the corridor that my locker is in is quite dark anyways, and would probably not be able to power the transistor.

*Question* Is there some way I can detect if a door is opened or closed without using any power?

I'd be grateful for all suggestions

Comment: your first idea was the best. Sort a switch out and it's job done. Mount the button suffuciently far back that the door can't knock it off. You could use a push-rod from the button to the door if there's no suitable place right behind the door to mount it. No quiescent power, low complexity, metal contacts FTW.

Comment: The search term is "micro switch". These are used on microwave oven doors and millions of other things. You may also be able to find a magnetic switch where the magnet (on the door) keeps the switch open, and when the door is opened the switch closes.

Comment: Re, "micro switch." Looks like this: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/SS-5GL2/SW156-ND/137204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then a friend suggested that I put in a button that would be pressed when the door was closed, opening the circuit with the LEDs, and closing the circuit when the door was opened. This would be very battery effective, but it is hard to place a button correctly, and it would propably come off if I accidentally closed the door with to much force.

I think you really should use a *normally closed push button* as your friend suggest and **tackle the drawbacks mechanically**:

Use e.g. a guided rod in combination with a spring to press the button.
The spring can solve the mounting misalignment issue to some extend as well as the slam-the-door issue.
**EDIT:** Of course those have been invented already: search internet on "spring rod limit switch".
[image]

Source (for as long as it exists there): www.alibaba.com

Another option is using a roller lever switch like shown below:

[image]

Source: [Technical Guide of Basic Switches by Omron](https://www.ia.omron.com/support/guide/29/explanation_of_terms.html)

Comment: Another related option that doesn't warrant a whole answer- A magnetic reed switch accomplishes this same task without any need for any mechanical design. Simply attach a magnet to the locker door in close proximity to where the magnetic reed switch is located inside the locker, and viola! The job is done. The hardest part is finding a reed switch that can handle that much current.

Comment: +1 -- this was about to be my answer. Same thing we use on industrial control panels to have the panel's task lighting turn on automatically.

Comment: I would use the roller lever switch (aka micro switch). Hot glue it or use contact cement to stick it to the frame of the locker door. Contact cement may slightly deface the locker when you remove it (it may take some of the paint with it when you pull it off).